# Not found --rcfile in bash

Tags: bash, shell

This line from shell script

```
${SHELL} --rcfile ${tf}
```

gives me the following output

```
./baxter.sh: line 178: --rcfile: command not found
```

In different computer it works well, so what can be wrong?

Comment: It's trying to execute `--rcfile` as a command, but it looks like it's supposed to be an option to whatever command is in `$SHELL`  Are you sure that variable is set properly?

Comment: Thank you, my SHELL variable was empty, I fixed it by adding there /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to your $SHELL add this /bin/bash